# ASP.NET MVC : can't update database item relation to null

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a post method to edit a database entry and its relations with other models items (in this case a client item). While this method does let me change a relation from one client to another, I just can't seem to be able to set it back to null once the relation has been made.

By this, I mean that the `subProject.Client = null` does actually set the value for the `subProject` item to null, but when updating the database, this change doesn't end up happening.

Here's the method:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> EditSubProject(int id, [Bind("Id,Name,Description,Price,Client")] SubProject subProject, int? selectedClientId)
{
    if (id != subProject.Id)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        try
        {
            subProject.Status = selectedStatusId;

            if (selectedClientId != 0)
            {
                subProject.Client = _context.Clients.Find(selectedClientId);
            }
            else
            {
                subProject.Client = null;
            }

            _context.Update(subProject);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
        catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
        {
            if (!SubProjectExists(subProject.Id))
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            else
            {
                throw;
            }
        }

        return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index);
    }

    return View(subProject);
}
```

Does the `_context.Update` just not work when severing the relation (or in other words setting it to null)? Or am i missing something else? And also yes, I've made sure that the relation to client is nullable in the model.